# Android stream audio from youtube with media player

Tags: android, audio, youtube, android-mediaplayer, rtsp

How do I stream audio from YouTube using Android `MediaPlayer`? According to the docs, RTSP format is supported. I managed to get the RTSP link of a video from Youtube, however it just throws an unknown error (1, -2147483648). Links to MP3s work fine. How do I get a valid RTSP link of a Youtube video that `MediaPlayer` will accept? And how do I do this programmatically, using only the Youtube video id (the one provided by the Youtube data API)?

Here is the RTSP link I used which caused the error: 
rtsp://r1---sn-5hn7su76.googlevideo.com/Ck0LENy73wIaRAkflqNqRsS_0xMYDSANFC3Rd0tWMOCoAUIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYIv1vJbH347rVYoBC3pLQmxnczU2WTV3DA==/1A9A62D72F83EA65A6D8E47DE0EE09DE43563B0A.42754FD04BA59E613D5903722D13C56521C2CC4A/yt6/1/video.3gp